# three sigma vs six sigma

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation, quality-control

I wonder about the meaning of the term [six sigma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_Sigma). It describes a process/production with (mostly) zero defects. You can see here:

[image: img]
source: https://www.dummies.com/article/business-careers-money/business/operations/how-six-sigma-can-benefit-your-operations-management-162941

but what I wonder is that, for me, the opposite should be the case: The more sigmas (standard devations), the broader the distribution should become resp. the broader the single "data points" are.

[image: img2]
source: https://www.intechopen.com/chapters/17405

So my question is: How/why is six sigma better than e.g. three sigma?

Is it due to the amount of sigmas to reach the LSL/USL?
In case of ~3 three sigmas it looks like one needs, well, three sigmas to reach the specification boundary and for six sigmas it might be six.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly, it's related to the number of sigmas to reach the LSL/USL from the mean of the distribution B compared to distribution A. There is an excerpt from the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_Sigma#Etymology) that explains this fairly well:

> Specifically, say that there are six standard deviations—represented
> by the Greek letter σ (sigma)—between the mean—represented by μ
> (mu)—and the nearest specification limit. As process standard
> deviation goes up, or the mean of the process moves away from the
> center of the tolerance, **fewer standard deviations will fit between
> the mean and the nearest specification limit, decreasing the sigma
> number and increasing the likelihood of items outside specification**.
> According to a calculation method employed in process capability
> studies, this means that practically no[failed verification] items
> will fail to meet specifications.